# what's wrong with this code?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$child= array();
$i = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $child[i] = $row['userId'];
    $i++;
} 

$i = 0;
while($i<=5)
{
    echo $child[i];
    $i++;
}
```

It is printing same value.

Comment: What's the query in $result ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `i` for the array index instead of `$i`:

```
$child[i]
```

This should be `$child[$i]`. Because the `i` in `$child[i]` is interpreted as a constant (value of constant `i` is used as index) or if there is no such constant as string. You can get a variable/value dump with [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump).

Comment: +1. Whatever happened to the good ole' days where the 'first correct answer gets the vote'.

Comment: I don't know what happened to those days, I didn't vote on myself. Maybe people liked the smiley face at the end, I myself think this answer is better formatted (and posted 1 minute before mine) so should be on top.

Comment: And yet another reason why you should test with the E_NOTICE error level set...

Answer (score 6):

you forgot an $i in $child[i].. should be $child[$i] ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you want numeric indexes you can do without $i .. try ..

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $child[] = $row['userId'];
} 

for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{    
echo $child[$i].' <br />;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
$child= array();
$i = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $child[$i] = $row['userId'];
    $i++;
} 

 $i = 0;
while($i<=5)
{
    echo $child[$i];
    $i++;
}
```

You weren't calling $i, but "i"